# Changing BlackBerry Locale

Tags: blackberry, localization

I need to switch Locate in my app between Arabic and English.

I have the following code to switch locale:

```
if (Locale.getDefault() == Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_ar, null)) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_en, null));  
} else {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_ar, null));
}
```

And in my app I have the following resource files:

- appName.rrh
- appName.rrc
- appName_ar.rrc
- appName_en.rrc

And I have a button which uses a localized string as follows:

```
subscribeButton = new ButtonField(res.getString(LANG), ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
```

My problem is when the locale is changed to Arabic, the UI flips (Arabic is right to left), and switching it again to English flips  it again, but all without the text in the button changing. Please guide me on what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because, you have created the button field with the text which was relevant for that locale. Once the locale changes, you will have to re set the buttonField text as

```
subscribeButton.setLabel(res.getString(LANG));
```

Comment: So how can I reload the whole UI when the locale is changed?

Comment: When you change the locale, call a refresh() method in your screen which refreshes the UI by setting buttonfields etc.